# Which institution (government or private) provides the complete data on HS (Harmonized System Code), tariff schedules for India, China and US?

Tags: data-request, international-trade, free-trade

Was looking out for options on building a data store having HS code and tariff schedule data for few countries, which I can use as a base for import calculations and general HS lookup.

Is there a government or private body (specifically for the countries US, China and India) from which I can source this data in a digital format, which of course I may further process according to my storage model.

Just a note: I'm aware that there already exist websites and applications which provide cost calculations services as limited free and on chargeable terms.

Answer (score 1):

The best place for this information is WTO TAO. The data does require a little cleaning but you have information on a countries' mfn